# Как решить эту задачу с увеличением числа на процент?

Tags: php

Дано число, вводимое пользователем. К примеру, 100 или 1000. Надо увеличить число на 30% и 120%, чтобы при вводе 100 выводило числа 130 и 220, а при 1000 - 1300 и 2200.

```
    <?php
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $x);
    echo $x = (($x / 100) * 130);
    echo $x = (($x / 100) * 220);
    ?>
```

И если первый вывод правильный, то второй уже выводит число, взятое из первого вывода, то бишь не 220, а 286.

Вопрос: как решить эту задачу, и можно ли после первого вывода, экранировать его, чтобы вторым выводило 220?

Comment: А зачем у вас присваивание в `echo`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen значение, полученное при вычислении присваивается $x. Или это можно решить другим способом?

Comment: ну так просто выводите результат и не меняйте переменную, где то так `echo ($x / 100) * 130;`

Comment: Ну так если оно присваивается `$x` то во втором `echo`  значение `$x` уже __не равно начальному__. Так ведь?

Comment: Уберите обе подстроки `$x =`

Comment: @KoVadim О, получилось. Спасибо